# Eight letter word, I am

Tags: word, affix-riddle

I start this word

My enemy follows me to the end

I am at the end of this word

I am also present just before the end

There is a living thing in the middle

What is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are the 8-letter word...

> **[MEANTIME](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meantime)**

*I start this word*

> It begins with **ME** ('I').

*My enemy follows me to the end*

> Your enemy is **ANTI-ME**, which follows 'ME' right to the end of the word.

*I am at the end of this word*

> **ME** ('I') is also at the end of the word.

*I am also present just before the end*

> **I** comes just before the final 'ME'. Alternatively, **I'M** ('I am') comes just before the final letter of the word (which is also the end of 'TH**E**', if you want to go super-cryptic-crossword!).

*There is a living thing in the middle*

> The word **ANT** - a living thing - can be found in the middle.

Comment: Wow again @Stiv. Note vz vf whfg orsber r ng gur raq

Comment: @RogerA Modified accordingly :)

Comment: What's "ANTI-ME"? I can't find it in dictionary. Or is it simply refers to enemy of "me"?

Comment: @justhalf The latter - it's not a real word, but it gives the impression of someone who is against you, i.e. an enemy. It's more a case of wordplay rather than a strict definition.

Comment: Hello @justhalf. Can you please your comments in rot13 form. It gives out the answer and  a lot of readers want to solve it by themselves. Thanks

Comment: Ok, done and dusted!

Answer (score 0):

Are you:

> **Illimani** - a mountain in the Andes?

Because:

I start this word

> 'I' is the first letter.

I am at the end of this word

> 'I' is the last letter'; also there is an 'am' if you read it backwards.

I am also present just before the end

> There is another 'i' in the middle of the word.

There is a living thing in the middle

> There is a 'man' in the middle of Illi**man**i.

Comment: My enemy follows me to the end