# The answer is in front of you

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle

> I'm myself most of the time, but a third I am not
> I'll trick you, my boy, like an insect you caught
> I start, I end, but I'm not in my middle
> I'm here right now, all throughout this riddle

**Who am I?**

Comment: Is this not the same riddle as https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117851/eight-letter-word-i-am/117852?noredirect=1#comment329562_117852 ?

Comment: @Astralbee not at all - different riddle, different answer

Comment: That was not my intention, but i was curious if they have the same answer or not.

Comment: rot13: va sebag bs lbh

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are the word:

> **CONSONANT**!

*I'm myself most of the time, but a third I am not*

> The word CONSONANT has 6 consonants (the majority of the word) and 3 vowels (a third of the word).

*I'll trick you, my boy, like an insect you caught*

> CON + SON + ANT

*I start, I end, but I'm not in my middle*

> The first letter ('start') is a consonant (C), as is the last letter ('end'): T. But the middle letter is 'O', a vowel.

*I'm here right now, all throughout this riddle*

> There's an awful lot of consonants in the text of this riddle!

As for the title:

> Not only are there many consonants on the screen in front of you right now, but the 'front of **Y**OU' is a consonant (Y), and in the English alphabet there's a consonant (T) directly in front of 'U'!

Comment: PS I love how this riddle bears a resemblance to [the other](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117851/eight-letter-word-i-am?noredirect=1&lq=1) posted just a few minutes before, but has absolutely no similarity in its solution - nice creative touch :)

Comment: How did I know that you'd be the one to get this :P Don't forget the title! And yep inspired by that after trying out this answer for that one (lets ignore the fact it's not 8 letters... I can count I swear)

Answer (score 2):

Alternate (and perhaps lame) solution:

> myself - i.e. “I”, ego, ...

I'm myself most of the time, but a third I am not

> I'm myself, I feel, I think, I have qualia etc... But one third of time we sleep.

I'll trick you, my boy, like an insect you caught

> [That old tricky grammar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/which-one-is-correct-to-say-its-me-or-its-i), where formally you'd expect “I” as a nominative subject complement in sentences like “It's I”, although the standard English uses the objective case: “It's me” (considered often incorrect from the prescriptivists' point of view).

I start, I end, but I'm not in my middle

> The word “I” starts with the letter I, ends with the letter I, but since it is a one letter word, it has no middle.

I'm here right now, all throughout this riddle

> Each of the lines in the riddle starts with an “I”